# How to import specified class (or varaibles from this class) to another class?

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes:
First and second class - have variables as listed below:

**First class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project_1
{
    class First_class
    {
        int variable_1 = 1;
        int variable_2 = 1;
        int variable_3 = 3;
        string variable_4 = "test1"

    }
}
```

**Second class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project_1
{
    class Second_class
    {
        int variable_5 = 5;
        int variable_6 = 6;
        int variable_7 = 7;
        string varaible_8 = "test_2"

    }
}
```

**Third class is empty:**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

1. What should I do to have possibility to use all variables from First class - in Third Class ?
2. What should I do to have possibility to use only some variables from First class and only some variables from Second class - in Third Class ?

Comment: You need to pass instances of the classes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by use? Should this properties be also properties on third class ? Use this properties from class1 and 2 in the third class meaning access them and od operations with them but they would still be properties of class 1 and 2 ? Or something else?

Comment: In general I would like to call these variables (from class 1 and 2) - in the third class

Comment: Please provide a sample of how you *want* third class to work (some non-compiling code basically). Its still unclear what you wan the behavior of that to be.

Comment: Third class will be a test class with Selenium so it would be better to have option to call ale variables

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use those variables outside of First_class, they **must** be declared as *public* variables.

```cs
class First_class
{
    public static int variable_1 = 1; // This can be accessed from outside
    public int variable_2 = 1; // This can be accessed from outside too
    int variable_3 = 3; // This can not be accessed from outside
    string variable_4 = "test1"; // This also can not be accessed from outside
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new First_class();
        Console.Writeline(First_class.variable_1);
        Console.Writeline(o.variable_2);
        Console.Writeline(o.variable_3); // Error: variable_3 is private
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but It looks that it is necessary - to declare all variables as public (separately for all variables in class).

Is there any other option that will make that all variables from the class will be public ?

Comment: Josué please don't use bold text style like this, especially when your statement is not literally correct. Also internal fields are accessible, as well as protected in some cases and a few other special cases also exist.

Comment: @Michal, nop, sorry, in C# you cant do that (in C++ you can). Instance fields of a class are private by default, unless you explicitly tell the compiler otherwise. The full set of visibility modifiers are private, protected, internal and public. You could declare the entity as struct, instead of class, in that case fields are public by default, but I strongly recommend you to not do that because structs are very different from classes: you cant inherit from them, they are copied by value (classes are copied by reference), etc

Comment: @AlKepp are you talking about using Reflection?? if thats the case, then you are right, but the dude seems to be starting at learning C#. Besides, i think using Reflection for accesing private/protected fields is a violation of the OOP paradigm principles and must be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

1.Here you have two possibilities:

a) To use all variables from First class in Third Class you have to make all of them public.

b) You can make all of them static and public or protected but in such case, the Program class needs to inherit
from the First class so it would look like:

```
public class First_class
{
    protected static int variable_1 = 1;
    protected static int variable_2 = 1;
    protected static int variable_3 = 3;
    protected static string variable_4 = "test1";
}

class Program: First_class
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(variable_1);
        Console.WriteLine(variable_2);
        Console.WriteLine(variable_3);
        Console.WriteLine(variable_4);
    }
 }
```

2.The example:

```
class Second_class
{
    int variable_5 = 5;
    int variable_6 = 6;
    int variable_7 = 7;
    public string varaible_8 = "test_2"; //only this field can be accessed
}

public class First_class
{
    public int variable_1 = 1;
    public int variable_2 = 1;
    protected int variable_3 = 3; // can be accessed via inheritance
    private string variable_4 = "test1"; // cannot be accessed due to privacy level
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj1 = new First_class();
        Console.WriteLine(obj1.variable_1);
        Console.WriteLine(obj1.variable_2);

        var obj2 = new Second_class();
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.varaible_8);

    }
}
```